# SOQL for records in a 7 day range?

Tags: apex, soql, date

I'm facing a problem in figuring out a SOQL query for the following scenario.
There's an object say X with a custom date field `Start_Date__c`. Now, I want records belonging to X with start date till 7 days after this start date. So, say start date is 1st then records with start date till 8th have to be retrieved.

Any help on the SOQL for this?

Comment: Are you doing this query in `Apex`?

Comment: Yes. Will have to frame a SOQL query which I would use in Conga (appExchange product for generating documents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is to define date variables and merge them in.

```
Date startDate = Date.newInstance(2017, 3, 1); // for instance
Date endDate = startDate.addDays(7);
List<MyObject__c> records = [
    SELECT ... FROM MyObject__c
    WHERE Start_Date__c >= :startDate
    AND Start_Date__c < :endDate
];
```

Just checked and confirmed that you can actually add/subtract days directly in the query:

```
List<MyObject__c> records = [
    SELECT ... FROM MyObject__c
    WHERE Start_Date__c >= :startDate
    AND Start_Date__c < :startDate+7
];
```

Comment: Got it. I was thinking if I could achieve this is in a single SOQL but that's not possible. Thanks!

Comment: Note that using <= and >= means this will actually get 8 days of records, including 3/1 and 3/8. OP is not clear on their logic, but I would expect to want `WHERE Start_Date__c >= :startDate AND Start_Date__c < :endDate`.